# Best practice for annotation in lines of align for derivation?

Tags: equations, amsmath

When presenting a lengthy mathematical derivation that draws upon previously introduced theorems or equations, it is good practice to write down the derivation line for line (e.g. using the `align` environment) and then adding the number of the theorem or equation used in a particular step at either the left or right margin of the line where it is applied.

Is there a package or a good, clean way to accomplish this? I feel that my current approach of using `alignat{2}` instead is a bit clumsy.

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
  & &   foo &= bar \\
  \text{Lemma \ref{lem:Bla} &\quad & foo &= boo
\end{alignat}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\tag` macro in any of the `amsmath` display environments to put a label on a line of an equation, for example a theorem you want to refer to.  If you also want a genuine line number, you have to do a bit of programming or else the `\tag` redefines the "number" that `\ref` will print to be whatever tag you chose (probably not what you want for a line number).  Here's a rough attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\let\mylabel=\label
\newcommand*{\referto}[2]{
 \refstepcounter{equation}%
 \mylabel{#2}
 \tag*{by Lemma \ref{#1} \quad  (\theequation)}%
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{lem}
  \label{lem:one}
  We have foo equal to bar.
 \end{lem}

 \begin{lem}
  \label{lem:two}
  We have foo equal to boo.
 \end{lem}

 That is, we have
 \begin{align}
  \text{foo} &= \text{bar} \referto{lem:one}{line:one} \\
  \text{foo} &= \text{boo} \referto{lem:two}{line:two} \\
  \text{boo} &= \text{bar} \label{line:three}
 \end{align}
 whence the theorem (see lines \ref{line:one}, \ref{line:two}, \ref{line:three}).

\end{document}
```

The only totally opaque piece is the `\mylabel` command.  As it turns out, `amsmath` redefines `\label` to play with `\tag`, but we don't want this, so we just save the original version for our own use.

Comment: That would work. But what if I also want that equation to have number which I can use `\ref` to refer to later?

Comment: I've included an attempt at this, though it could be polished more.